# Fixing Python Code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to  implement an iterator class named CharCounter. This class opens a textfile and provides an iterator that returns words from the text file containing a user specified number of characters. It should output a word per line. Which is not what's it's doing, it's outputting the words as a list and then it continuously outputs 'a'. How can I fix my code?

```
class CharCounter(object):
     def __init__(self, fileNm, strlen):
        self._fileNm = fileNm
        self._strlen = strlen
        fw = open(fileNm)
        text = fw.read()

        lines = text.split("\n")
        words = []
        pwords =[]

        for each in lines:
            words += each.split(" ")

        chkEnd = ["'",'"',",",".",")","("]
        if words[-1] in chkEnd:
            words = words.rstrip()

        for each in words:
            if len(each) == strlen:
                 pwords.append(each)

        print(pwords)

     def __iter__(self):
         return CharCounterIterator(self._fileNm)

class CharCounterIterator(object):
    def __init__(self,fileNm):
        self._fileNm = fileNm
        self._index = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        try:
            ret = self._fileNm[self._index]
            return ret
         except IndexError:
             raise StopIteration

if __name__=="__main__":
     for word in CharCounter('agency.txt',11):
        print "%s" %word
```

Comment: Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead. I doubt anyone would help you here.

Comment: well what's wrong with your code

Comment: "Fix" and "improve" are very different. "Fixing" means "repairing the code that doesn't work", or, "making erroneous code work correctly", but "improving" is "making already working, correct code work 'better'".

Comment: @hspandher should only recommend that site if it's bug free. Since OP states fix/improve it could be imply that it has some bugs and errors which would be off topic on codereview. As for your second comment, if the code doesn't work, and OP edited his question, people would help out... either way both your statements seems a bit misleading.

Comment: @hspandher: It's dangerous to recommend another site without being sure that it will fit. This question exactly as it stands would probably be closed there because it seems to have broken code and there's no description.

Answer (score 0):

Code posted on SO should not read a file unless the question is about reading files.  The result cannot be duplicated and verified.  (See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).) Instead, define a text string as a stand-in for the file.

Your code prints the words of length n as a list because that is what you ask it to do with `print(pwords)`.  It repeatedly prints the first char of the filename because that is what you ask it to do in the `__next__` method.

Your class `__init__` does more than you describe.  The attempt to strip punctuation from words does not do anything.  The code below defines a class that turns a text into a list of stripped words (with duplicates).  It also defines a parameterized generator method that filters the word list.

```
class Words:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.words = words = []
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            for word in line.split():
                words.append(word.strip(""",'."?!()[]{}*$#"""))
    def iter_n(self, n):
        for word in self.words:
            if len(word) == n:
                yield word

# Test
text = """
It should output a word per line.
Which is not what's it's doing!
(It outputs the words as a [list] and then continuously outputs 'a'.)
How can I fix my #*!code?
"""
words = Words(text)
for word in words.iter_n(5):
    print(word)

# Prints
Which
doing
words
```